# Observe flow as Compose string state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a Composable and a viewmodel (VM) for it. The VM gets some data from a kotlin flow which I would like to expose as a State

Usually I would have the VM expose a state like this:

```
var title by mutableStateOf("")
    private set
```

And I could use it in the Composable like this

```
Text(text = viewModel.title)
```

But since the data comes from a flow, i have to expose it like this

```
@Composable
fun title() = flowOf("TITLE").collectAsState(initial = "")
```

And have to use it in the Composable like this

```
Text(text = viewModel.title().value)
```

I try to minimize boilerplate code, so the `.value` kind of bothers me. Is there any way to collect the flow as state, but still expose it as `viewModel.title` or `viewModel.title()` and get the actual String and not the state object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegated property.If your program just read it.

```kotlin
class FlowDeletedProperty<T>(val flow: Flow<T>, var initialValue: T, val scope: CoroutineScope) :
    ReadOnlyProperty<ViewModel, T> {
    private var _value = mutableStateOf(initialValue)

    init {
        scope.launch {
            flow.collect {
                _value.value = it
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: ViewModel, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return _value.value
    }
}

fun <T> ViewModel.flowDeletedProperty(flow: Flow<T>, initialValue: T) =
    FlowDeletedProperty(flow, initialValue, viewModelScope)
```

in viewModel

```kotlin
val a = flow {
        while (true) {
            kotlinx.coroutines.delay(100L)
            println("out ")
            emit((100..999).random().toString())
        }
    }
val title by flowDeletedProperty(a,"")
```

in ui

```kotlin
Text(text = viewModel.title)
```